# Could not find a declaration file for module xlsx

Tags: excel, angular

I am learning Angular 2 and I am trying to Download the Excel file in angular 2 by fetching customer data from sql server tables using web api.

After searching in google i found some code but using that code i am geeting an error like 'Could not find a declaration file for module xlsx'

I have installed below

npm install xlsx  --save

npm install file-saver --save

and below is the code i have used:

**Download Component**

```
            import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
            import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

            import { Component, EventEmitter, Input,Injectable, Inject, enableProdMode, AfterViewInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
            import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
            import {HttpService} from '../http.service';
            import { AppModule } from '../app.module'; 
            import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
            import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
            import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

            const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
            const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';


            import 'rxjs/Rx' ;

            @Component ({  
               selector: 'my-app',  
               templateUrl:'./excelDownload.html',
               providers:[HttpService]
            })  
            @Injectable()
            export class ExcelDownloadComponent {  
                constructor(private httpService: HttpService )
                {

                }
                public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
                    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
                    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
                    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
                    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
                  }

                  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
                    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
                      type: EXCEL_TYPE
                    });
                    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
                  }
                GetRemindersData()
                {
                     var Flag="ALL_SPOTCHECK_RECORDS";
                     this.httpService.GetRemindersData(Flag).subscribe(
                     data=>this.exportAsExcelFile((data[1]),"Spot_Check"),
                     error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
                     () => console.info("OK"));

                }

              }
```

**Http service.ts**

```
                import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

                import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

                import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


                import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

                // Import RxJs required methods
                import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
                import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


                @Injectable()
                export class HttpService {

                        constructor( private http: Http) { }
                        public GetRemindersData(Flag:string){

                        var GetRemindersData_URL:string = 'http://localhost:5000/api/RemindersData/?Flag='+Flag;


                        return this.http.get(`${GetRemindersData_URL}`)
                                    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                                    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Note: I am not using angualr cli and i have clone the start up project from github

Comment: I would recommend using angualr cli :-) it works there i have tested :-)

Comment: What is that the actual error message you get?  Have you tried building with the `--aot` option?